# Google sign in - GoogleSignInAccount returns null

Tags: android, google-api

Im trying to integrate a google sign in my app but it keeps failing and GoogleSignInAccount returns a null object and it displays cancelled. I dont know whats going wrong. Is it this or the dependencies? This is my code in onCreate

```
    GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestProfile()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
            .build();


    final SignInButton googleLoginButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googleLoginButton);
    googleLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
            googleSignIn();
        }
    });
```

And these are the other functions

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // do nothing
}

private void googleSignIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        if (acct != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome " + acct.getDisplayName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancelled!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you put package name and SHA1 key in google cloud console for your project ?

Comment: Try to ask the email of the user Like that : .requestEmail() in your googleSignInOptions.

Comment: @HiteshSarsava Yes I did. How can I check if its done

Comment: @Itoun It still says cancelled

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating see this link and click on configure project

Comment: are you running your project in debug mode or release mode?